# Wifi Network Adapter not detected by Windows after BSOD

Tags: windows-7, bsod, wifi-driver

I have Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on a Dell Inspiron Laptop. I also have Ubuntu 11.10 as a dual boot option on this machine.

Recently I got a BSOD with the following error -

DRIVER POWER STATE FAILURE

Since then Windows does not recognize the Wifi network adapter. It is not there in the Device Manager at all.

It does not seem to be a hardware problem because when I boot using Ubuntu, the Wifi works without any problem.

Can anyone guide me how to solve this issue. Since the adapter is not being listed in the device manager, I don't know how to update or reinstall drivers.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any wifi management tools in All Programs? Also, open Network and Sharing, can it to a repair?

Comment: There is Intel My Wifi Technology. However when I start it, it stays blank with the message - No supported Intel Wireless Network Adapter was found in this computer.

Network and Sharing does not show any wireless network at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got the solution.

The trick was to go to Control Panel > Device Manager > Network Adapters and the Right-click and select "Scan for Hardware Changes". Windows scanned the entire hardware and signalled to itself that there is a wifi adapter attached.

Somehow the BSOD had made some changes in the system so that it appeared that there was no wifi adapter installed.